# Hiding Custom Field in WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have added a custom button next to the woocommerce 'Add to cart' button.

```
// Enquire Now Button
function wc_shop_enquire_button() {
echo '<a class="button enquire-button" href="'.get_field( 
"enquire_button_link" ).'">'.get_field( "enquire_button_text" 
).'</a>';
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 
'wc_shop_enquire_button', 20 );
```

But I need to hide the button when the fields are empty.

Id appreciate any help you can give.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the vriable is empty or not and add button if it is not empty

```
// Enquire Now Button
function wc_shop_enquire_button() {
    if(!empty(get_field( "enquire_button_text"))){
        echo '<a class="button enquire-button" href="'.get_field( 
        "enquire_button_link" ).'">'.get_field( "enquire_button_text" 
       ).'</a>';
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button','wc_shop_enquire_button', 20 );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    function wc_shop_enquire_button() {
        if(get_field( "enquire_button_text")!='')
        {
        echo '<a class="button enquire-button" href="'.get_field( 
        "enquire_button_link" ).'">'.get_field( "enquire_button_text" 
        ).'</a>';
        }
      }
 add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 'wc_shop_enquire_button', 20 );
```